# Pagination doesn't work on multiple categories

Tags: categories, menus, pagination

I have the following problem.
In my custom menu (`wp_nav_menu`) I added a category.
This category uses the template `category.php`.
Now I have multiple categories that are shown on the page.
My problem is that the pagination doesn't work.
It shows the link en all but page/2/ display's an 'page not found'-page.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

See my code:

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // allow for pagination
        $getcat = query_posts('category_name=array("cat1", "cat2", "cat3","cat4","cat5","cat6")'); 
        $args = array (
            $getcat,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        query_posts($args);
    ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="some_class"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
            <div class="pagination">
                <div class="ex_previous"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; recent', 0); ?></div>
                <div class="ex_next"><?php next_posts_link('older &raquo;', 0); ?></div>
            </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope anyone can tell me where I went wrong

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wrong with you query. I will explain as I go along

Firstly, you should never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to construct custom queries. This is not just my emphasis, but the codex as well. The one big problem with `query_posts` is, it many circumstances, pagination fails

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Secondly, the parameter that you've used `category_name` excepts a string, not an array.

Thirdly, you've run two occurences of `query_posts` where only one is actually needed. This is also why your pagination out right fails

Fouthly, your [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) `$max_pages` parameter should be set for custom queries, otherwise it will fail

OK, to come to the business end, you need to construct you custom query with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), keeping in mind some of the points I've raised above.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ?  get_query_var('paged') : 1; // this section is correct, allows pagination

 $args = array( //set-up arguments to pass to WP_Query
    'category_name' => 'string of category slugs, not name', // can use 'cat' parameter with string of category ID
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' = $paged
  );

$query = new WP_Query( $args); //add arguments back to WP_Query

if($query->have_posts()) :  while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); //start the loop
  <-----YOUR LOOP---->
 endwhile;
  <----YOUR PAGINATION---->
     Remember next_posts_link should look something like 'next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $query->max_num_pages );'
wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;
```

Comment: WOW. Nice detailed explanation. Thnx. It still doesn't work. I wrote a detailed answer but since I have no reputation over 10 I can't comment :-( So.... I have to wait 8 hours.

Comment: Since I saw the link I get the idea there is some error here:
I added the category 'news' to the menu. That category uses the template `category.php`
the above code is used on `category.php`. Doesn't the pagination expects a page where only the posts from category 'news' are?

M.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work.

Comment: I think your question is wrongly worded. I think what you are looking for is when you click on a category, lets say news, you are taken to a page showing posts from the news category, and when you go to page two, the next set of posts are shown from the news category

Comment: What I tried to explain in my previous post is that I need to list all the posts from multiple categories. But I realised that I added a category called news to my menu. The news category uses the `category.php`-template where the above code is used. I think I need to create a page-template that uses this code and a new page with the template

Comment: And that's the way the cookie crumbles:-) I just tried it and it works. ThnQ for your help and effort

Comment: Yes, that will be the best. My code will work perfect there.